# Sort products by In stock in magento 2.4

Tags: product-list, category-products, sorting, magento2.4.1, product-sorting

Can we sort products In stock only.

see the below screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can enable it from the backend.

Admin -> Stores -> Attributes -> Products -> quantity_and_stock_status -> Used for Sorting in Product Listing = Yes

Comment: I want to show only Instock Products instead of all

Comment: For that, you can use a filter instead of sorting. because in sorting all product data arrange by particular order and in a filter you will get only that data which you want.
or if you don't want to show out of products at all then you can set from the admin
Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory -> Stock Options -> Display Out of Stock Products = No

Answer (score 0):

Set Display Out of Stock Products configuration to "No" in the backend

`Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory -> Stock Options -> Display Out of Stock Products`

Comment: we allow backordered so we displayed out of stock products in frontend.